# How to detect swipe direction, touch position, etc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

If I wanted to build an app that incorporated very basic swipe detection, how could I determine swiping zones on the user view? For example, if programming a playable guitar, would it be possibly to create 6 long and narrow buttons to represent each guitar string, and then trigger a method due to a swiping event instead of a 'press' event?

Currently, my only experience with triggering buttons is with touchUpInside, and was wondering if there was something like swipeLeftToRight or swipteRightToLeft.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use gesture recognizers. See `UIGestureRecognizer`. You can also you `touchesBegan:` etc on `UIView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility: Divide your interface into views (which could be invisible), one gesture recognizer per view. The gesture recognizer responds if the gesture is made in its view.

Another possibility: The whole interface is one big view with just one gesture recognizer, and you analyze the touches to figure out exactly *where* the gesture took place.

Comment: And my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll be sure to pour over your book. Just to clarify, it wouldn't be possible to simply define the area within a button or something to be a GestureRecognizer, and I should instead do what you said using views?

Comment: You want to detect a swipe. A button has a natural desire to detect a tap. So for now, I'd keep buttons out of it if I were you!

Answer (score 1):

Look into UIGestureRecognizers. They'll be attached to views and message a given selector.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Pardon my ignorance, but how do I associate this with an element in the view? Would I first make a button, and then somehow attach these UIGestureRecognizers to the button? I am used to defining interaction areas in the view by control-dragging objects, and don't know how to do that with UIGestureRecognizers

Comment: You have two options. If you want to use Interface Builder, there are objects you can drag to the object pane in IB. From there, they can be associated with views by doing a control + drag to the view you want to associate it with. If you're doing it within code, set up your gesture recognizer with the proper init methods then add it to your view using [self.theViewItShouldBeAddedTo addGestureRecognizer:theGestureRecognizerToAdd]. Sorry to be light on the details, but this is really a situation where it's all in the docs and we have no code in question to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

That's what a swipe gesture recognizer is used for ;-) (see below)

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:viewController
                                                                                    action:@selector(swipeLeftSelector:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I need to figure out how to associate a gesture recognizer with a specific part of the screen!